# Is this sentence grammatically and lexically correct?

Tags: sentence-usage

> All marketing research was objective, accurate and thorough, which allowed us to choose the optimal market outlet, to carry out planning, ie reasonable prediction, according to the results of marketing research, forecast of the market situation and development of appropriate marketing measures to ensure efficiency our business activities and the implementation of strategic directions of entrepreneurship.

Would you say that it is written by a native speaker?

Comment: It might have been written by a native speaker, but it is far too long and complicated to make sense. It's not clear to me what _i.e. reasonable_ refers to. I would advise breaking it down into two or three sentences.

Comment: Where did you find the sentence?

Comment: I translated it from Ukrainian to English. Just wanted to hear the opinion of native speakers.

Comment: Proofreading questions, such as this one, are not generally considered on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could very well have been written by a native speaker (or a committee of native speakers) even though it is ungrammatical, pretentious, and indecipherable. A great deal of business prose is written like that, particularly sales literature. It is intended to sound profound, but ends up meaning nothing.

For example, "to ensure efficiency our business activities and the implementation of strategic directions of entrepreneurship" is an ungrammatical list of buzz words.